# Transmission Torrent behind HAProxy - HTTP Response Header used as session identifier and stickiness token

Tags: haproxy, bittorrent

I've been trying, and failing so far, to run Transmission behind HAProxy.

If I just add a new backend and route traffic as follows:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    acl host1 hdr_end(host) -i web.host1.host
    use_backend apache_backend if host1

    acl transmission_host hdr_end(host) -i transmission.host1.host
    use_backend transmission_backend if transmission_host
```

Then I get a 409 conflict error stating I have an invalid session-id header. That's pretty obvious and expected since there's a proxy in the middle.

I thought of recompiling transmission to get rid of the check, but decided in the end to face the challenge of learning a bit more of HAProxy. What did I have in mind?

> 1. Client reaches HAProxy
> 2. HAProxy connects to transmission-daemon
> 3. Daemon replies with X-Transmission-Session-Id
> 4. HAProxy stores the Session-Id somehow and replaces Session-Id sent by the client with the one captured by HAProxy.

After a lot of Googling and playing with the settings, I got an almost working configuration:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    capture response header X-Transmission-Session-Id len 48

    acl host1 hdr_end(host) -i web.host1.host
    use_backend apache_backend if host1

    acl transmission_host hdr_end(host) -i transmission.host1.host
    use_backend transmission_backend if transmission_host

backend transmission_backend
    mode http
    http-request set-header X-Transmission-Session-Id %hs

    server transmission-daemon transmission.intranet:9091
```

My configuration examples are summarized.

It works, sort of. I get a login prompt for transmission, but the page loads incredibly slow. I'm more than 10 minutes in and still don't have it fully loaded.

More pages go through this proxy: HTTP, HTTPS, TCP, some load balanced, some set as fail-overs. They all load normally and fast. If I connect directly to the transmission-daemon server, it loads fast as well.

I'll keep looking around.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 years later,
from what I've seen in https://gist.github.com/yuezhu/93184b8d8d9f7d0ada0a186cbcda9273

you should capture request and response in frontend http-in,
I didn't dug much more, but the backend seems to need

```
stick-table type binary len 48 size 30k expire 30m
stick store-response hdr(X-Transmission-Session-Id)
stick on hdr(X-Transmission-Session-Id)
```

to work